# Avoiding middleware for static content in express app

Tags: express, middleware

I'm developing a small web app using express framework and I'm having a tough time with static content configuration.
In my app I have several custom middleware functions and I don't want the static files (css, js, images,...) to be processed by them. I tried to put static configuration as the first middleware but it doesn't fix anything.

My code is something like this:

```
var app = express();
app.configure(function() {
  app.set('port', 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  app.use(myCustomMiddleware());
});
```

I log the requests that reach my custom middleware and I can see requests to css and js (files inside *public* folder) getting there.

My goal is to return as soon as possible when receiving a static file request.

Any tips on this?
Thanks.

Comment: It *should* work as you expect, though: requests handled by the static middleware shouldn't be passed to your middleware at all. So I think there's something else going on, but hard to judge what exactly from what you're posting.

Comment: The files actually _exist_ in the `public` directory?  Because the file actually has to exist for the static middleware to handle it....

Comment: #Ethan yes, they do exist.

Comment: #robertklep I'll try to find some time to create a more elaborated example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm closing this question as the problem is my own code.

Trying to isolate the components I found that I was modifying incoming request URL unintentionally.